# Why does Event Delegation save memory?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, addeventlistener, event-delegation

I tried to understand how 'addEventListener' works like when we add event, where does it save? DOM tree? Or certain memory place?. But couldn't find answer, all the posts I've ever seen said "You can't", because there's no standard for it and every browser has different implementation.

So I was trying to skip it, but got a question about event delegation. In many posts, people say event delegation saves memory, because we don't have to attach event listener to each components. But I thought, I have to understand how addEventListener works to understand why event delegation saves memory.

So what's the reason event delegation is memory efficient?

Comment: But does it, really? I've seen a lot of JS problems, but too many `addEventListener`s consuming too much memory has never been one of them. I've always found the reason to use event delegation to make the *code's logic easier*, rather than for performance reasons.

Comment: Also wouldn't it effect speed more than memory use?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I also haven't heard of it, but people say it saves memory in many posts so I just want to know how it really works :/ I can't separate how it saves memory and how addEventListener works.

Comment: @OtherMe Anyway event goes down and have to go to target phase and bubbles. Is there any improvement on speed? I haven't think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in the browser's memory, there's a data structure that contains the list of event listeners for each element. If you call `addEventListener()` separately for 100 different elements, it will create 100 entries in this table.

But if you use event delegation, you only have to call `addEventListener()` once, so there's only 1 entry in the table.

You can actually see a representation of this data by opening the **Event Listeners** tab in the **Elements** panel of Developer Tools.

However, the amount of memory you save is probably not very significant. Each listener is probably just a couple of pointers, one to something representing the event type (click, change, etc.) and another to the callback function. If all 100 event listeners call the same function, there's just one function object and 100 pointers to it. If the function is a closure, there will also be an environment object containing the variables it closes over, which will add a little more memory use, but not very much.

On the other hand, when you use delegation, the callback function needs to do extra work to determine if the event target is an appropriate nested element. This makes it a little slower. It will also be called if the event is triggered on an element that's in the container element but not one of the elements you're delegated to (and will run repeatedly as the event bubbles out), so the function is run more often. If memory were really at a premium, this would be a classic time/space tradeoff.

In practice, delegation isn't used to save memory, it's used to simplify the design. It's most often used when you're adding elements to the DOM dynamically, or changing attributes (e.g. class names) that the event binding depends on. Delegation allows you to define the event listener once, rather than having to add or remove it from elements as they're added or modified.